# how should I test if port forwarding is working?

Tags: apache, ssh, portforwarding

I am doing a local forwarding to the remote port at 80 which the apache2 is listening on like this `ssh -L 80:localhost:80 user@host.com` , so it connects me to the remote server, however I find I can still do `mkdir` `rm` and such commands. Isn't it so that I am only forwarded to application listening on port 80? so what's the difference to this command `ssh -p 22 host.com` ? Is there a way to test if this port forwarding is working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Test as follows:

1. You should use a Client program on one Side and A Server Program on the other remote side.
2. Try to connect your client to your server according to ports and IP's used in your port forwarding by Netsh Cmd.
3. If connection succeed , that is it, if connection fails, that means port forwarding command  was failed, or your ip and port configuration of your client and server is wrong.
4. More over if you send a text file to the server, you should receive it.
   I hope that this will help.
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on port 80 with netcat like this on the host ...

```
nc -l -p 80
```

... and then either send something back with netcat ...

```
nc host.com 80 <<< hello
```

... and see if you get a "hello" on the server, or use nmap :

```
nmap host.com -p 80
```

You can also use nmap the same way if you already have a server listening on port 80, like apache.

Just note that nmap will say it's closed unless there is something listening on that port.